# Magento2 - How To Setup Magento Commerce Cloud In Local Development?

Tags: magento2.4, magento-2-commerce, magento-cloud

I am new In Magento cloud and I have to start the development. how to set up in local and how to deploy new code.

I have all details for cloud I am unable to set up in my local.

I clone the git repo in local. and trying run the command

```
sudo composer install
```

but it's giving an error

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
> The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-invitation/magento-module-invitation-100.4.0.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1
> 404 Not Found)

I have found a solution.  set private and public keys in  **auth.json**. keys set but still getting an error

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [guide from Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-mode-production.html) for working with Magento Cloud projects on your local environment using Docker.

Comment: how to get a source code and DB. and setup local??

Answer (score 0):

Setting the enterprise keys on **auth.json** file was working for me.

You can ask the admin to provide the keys especially if are a developer.

Or

You can check the keys in the project if you have SSH access.

```
magento-cloud variable:get env:COMPOSER_AUTH --level project
```